# Autogenerate SOAP requests from WSDL in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Im have searched a lot for a code-snippet to autogenerate a SOAP request based on a WSDL in PHP.

We have a 3'rd party vendor creating a huge WSDL ( + related webservices) for us , and I would really like to autogenerate some SOAP-requests in PHP based on that WSDL.
I know of application specific tools like SOAPUI etc - however - I prefer to do the unittesting directly in the PHP-code.

Do you know of any PHP lib to autogenerate SOAP requests based on a WSDL? Or even better, do you have a some code to autogenerate a SOAP request?

Answer (score 1):

use apigenerator.com to generate soap requests

Answer (score 1):

What i would recommend you is to use the soap components of the zend framework.

For example you just setup a soap client using :

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("url to wsdl file");

//Then you can do what ever request to the server.

$client->helloWorld("Parameter'); 
// In this example i guess helloWolrd is a server function.
```

and finally you can have the xml soap request calling:

```
$request = $client->getLastRequest();
```

just do:   echo $request; and you will see the data.

**Remember to change the mime code to xml so you can see the xml in the browser.**